# How to Decouple db repo from code repo with liquibase

Tags: git, liquibase

We have one database schema that serving multiple projects.
To start versioning and tracking changes we want to start using [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.com/).
We want to have 1 dedicated git repository for DB schema changes (ie. Liquibase files).

Is it a good idea to decouple the changes from the code and put it in a dedicated git repository?

If it’s a good option, then we need to setup the developer IDE to work with 2 repositories when push/pull?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good idea to decouple the changes from the code and put it in a dedicated git repo ?

That seems similar to what is explained in "[Handling Multiple Schemas with Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.com/blog/handling-multiple-schemas-with-liquibase)":

> When schemas – or databases – are shared across multiple teams, then it is not possible to use each team’s own application repository.
> This requires setting up a dedicated SQL repository for shared schemas/databases.
>
> [image: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/WV7fM4XcHpzMhVgBHWlRinLDxLGZH5cLlW6dt7sN_JCjIZKU7T-Vi5q-o9JwmLooJ9umNgo48JD8jYJk6Dbm2KIzboyqOaiMYZ8-LAchzsRRPzSb4JYJ-EGpIbUfFtHnEpW-YCndxb-_Py9iP8kR_oqaJE3mV68LoLDV6tSNN5igIJGCGZih8ANgeI7eTg]
>
> See "[Best Practices for Multiple Teams Deploying to the Same Database (Oracle)](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/multi-teams-same-db-oracle.html)"
> See "[Best Practices for Multiple Teams Deploying to the Same Instance (SQL Server)](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/multi-teams-same-db-sqlserver.html)"

You might consider referencing that dedicated repository as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)** in one current project repository.

That way, you always reference one specific commit/state of the DB repo in your project repository, and you would update said DB repo only when you need to.